# removing p tag around images from wordpress term_description

Tags: wordpress

Should be pretty straight forward but placing my filter in the themes function file is not having any affect on the template:

```
add_filter('term_description', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
   return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
```

and my markup:

```
 <?php echo term_description(); ?>
```

EDIT: I tried testing the filter by returning dummy content from the function and nothing changes, so the filter isn't running on the content for some reason

Comment: Have you tried using `'$1$2$3'` as your replacement?

Comment: Yes I have, not even sure if the filter is actually touching the content..

Comment: One way to check would be to simply return some dummy content...i.e. `return 'blah blah';`. If you see it, your filter is running properly.

Comment: Ok tried that so something is not working properly from the filter, no idea why

Comment: I even tried this plugin and altered it to term_description. No luck: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-p-tag-around-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was trying to target the wrong template and the actual function was an Advanced Custom Field wysiwg custom content tag:

```
<?php the_field('fieldname'); ?>
```

It took me a little while to figure out how to filter this but with a little googling I found out you can use this to target an ACF wysiwyg field from your functions file:

```
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'your_function');
```